# Wordpress ajax call not triggering for non website member

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, function, user-defined-functions

I am making ajax call to retrieve posts from functions.php and the following problem is particular to non website members only.It is triggering sometimes only and other times it is not triggering at all.

I am adding actions in functions.php in the following manner

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax_snp', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback_snp');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax_snp', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback_snp');
```

the following function is there in functions.php

```
<?php
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback_snp() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts_snp', 'security');
    $paged_snp= $_POST['page'];
    $args_snp = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '16',
        'cat' => '70',
        'paged' => $paged_snp,
        );
    $my_posts_snp = new WP_Query( $args_snp );
    if ( $my_posts_snp->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $my_posts_snp->have_posts() ) : $my_posts_snp->the_post() ?>
            <?php
            echo "<div>";
            Content
            echo "</div>";
            ?>
        <?php endwhile ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_die();
}
?>
```

I Am Using The Following Script To Call Posts On Page page-custom-template.php

```
<div class="loadmore" style="text-align:center;font-size:1.4em;color:#4a235a;padding:1% 0 1% 0;font-weight:900;">
<button id="lmb" type="button" style="background-color: #f44336;width:98%;border-radius:6px;border:2px solid #4a235a;outline:none;"><span id="lmp">Load More Posts</span><span id="lng" style="display:none;">Loading </span><img id="loader" src="http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/151309/loader.gif" width="25em;" height="25em;" id="lmi" style="display:none;"></button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var page = 2;
jQuery(function($) {
$('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {

    var data = {
        'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax_snp',
        'page': page,
        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts_snp"); ?>'
      };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        $('.my-posts').append(response);
        page++;
    });
});
});
</script>
```

How do I make it work perfectly for non subscribers and non logged in members ?

Comment: Can you hardcode the `<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>` part. I guess that part is "" for non-loggedin users

Comment: it is not possible for me to hard code that part.

Comment: what is the output when the function is not ping. check your console and let it share.

Comment: This is the error that I am getting

XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://src/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Line Number 1, Column 1:

Answer (score 1):

**First**

Why you don't use `WP debug`? Read this [topic](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).
Or write this code in `wp-config.php` and check log file in `wp-content` folder

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

**Second**

```
<?php
echo "<div>";
Content
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Why you don't close php tag `?>`, where you print your `Content`? For example:

```
<?php echo "<div>"; ?>
Content
<?php echo "</div>"; ?>
```

**Third**

Use this code for print `ajax_url`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 );
function myajax_data(){

    wp_localize_script('twentyfifteen-script', 'myajax', 
        array(
            'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        )
    );  

}
```

And you need to replace in js code

```
var ajaxurl = url;
```

Comment: I have executed the third part by adding the code to functions.php file.
is that right?
is it necessary that I execute first and second part?

Comment: I have added the code in third part to functions.php and it is not working

Comment: @TarunJain You need to replace `ajax_url` in your js code. Check my update. And if your code don't work, please read about wp debug

Comment: I understand now .. Thanks

Comment: @TarunJain You're welcome! If I helped you, please select my answer as correct. Thank you

Comment: I tried but it is not working.
I am looking into wp debug now

Comment: This is the error that I am getting

XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://src/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Line Number 1, Column 1: